# How to compute CI for reference group in multiple group SEM?

Tags: confidence-interval, structural-equation-modeling, group-differences, invariance

I am comparing several age groups on one latent factor with SEM in lavaan. The model shows strict invariance and i want to compare the latent means of the different age groups. To do so, i also want to use the 84% CIs of the latent means of the different groups. As the mean of my reference group is 0, how am i supposed to compute the CI of that group? In other studys there is a CI given even for the reference group.

Comment: You can identify the latent mean in each group by fixing the loading of one reference indicator to 1 and the intercept of the same reference indicator to 0 in each group. Then, you can estimate all latent means freely as well as their confidence intervals. Note that the reference indicator should be the same in each group.